# hijax not working with php extensions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

For some reason the follow code doesn't work when the file has a php extension:

```
<ul class="issues">
<li><a href="jobs.php">Jobs</a></li>
<li><a href="town-centres.php">Town Centre</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="input"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
var wrap = $('#input');
$('ul.issues a').on('click', function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    wrap.load(href + ' article');   
    e.preventDefault();
});
})();
 </script>
```

Works fine on locally but nothing appears on remote server unless I change the file extension to htm. Console shows XHR loaded. See [broken PHP version](http://www.savellandeilosfuture.org/issues-test.php) and [working `.htm` version](http://www.savellandeilosfuture.org/issues.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is what the PHP script is (or isn't in this case) returning ...

```
wrap.load(href + ' article');
```

This jQuery loads the `href` and just gets the `<article>` section and loads it into the `wrap` element. If you use something like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (or any browser debugger where you can see the content loaded using AJAX) you will see that the PHP script returns the following :

```
<div id="content">
<h1>Do new supermarkets really create jobs?</h1>
etc...
```

Where as the `.htm` version returns :

```
<div id="content">
<article>
<h1>Do new supermarkets really create jobs?</h1>
etc ...
```

So you can see the PHP doesn't reply with the `<content>` tag - hence no HTML is added to the `wrap` element

You have 2 options to fix the problem ..

1. Change the jQuery to `wrap.load(href + ' #content');`
2. Change the PHP script to include `<article>`